# Prove to me that this answer is correct

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm doubting myself and my teacher, so I need some external verification.

[image: Link to image]

So, the graph on the left is given to me, and I'm told to derive it. The answer key is shown on the right. What I do not understand is why $x = -5$, $-1$ and $3$ are not inclusive.

I understand that the limits at $x = -5$, $-1$ and $3$ do not exist, obviously. However, they are still derivable at those points, correct? Because in the original graph, they are clearly marked inclusive. It even says the domain is $[-5, \infty)$, so that completely means $-5$ is inclusive for $f(x)$. (That infinity one should really be a right parenthesis.)

So anyway, is my teacher wrong, or am I wrong? Can anyone actually prove to me in the most clear, concise manner possible that $f'(x)$ at the points $-5$, $-1$ and $3$ are non-inclusive?

Thank you for your time and help in advance. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Your teacher is correct.

Comment: The derivative is defined to be $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. That expression isn't even well-defined at points where there's a discontinuity, though a one-sided limit may be. It just makes things easier all round if we take derivatives only on open intervals.

Comment: I really can't see how this post deserves all the downvotes and close votes. It is a clearly posed question with motivations and personal thoughts on the matter. It's all we look for in questions on this site. Are we really going to give someone seven downvotes and a closure because of what? They don't have a detailed understanding of the subtleties of derivatives? Why is this site here if not to help exactly people like this?

Comment: The function is not continuous at those points, therefore its derivative doesn't exist

Comment: I don't see why this was closed either, there's clearly enough context. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Dylan Voted for reopen. Occasions like these always make me want to force people to give comments when down voting. No one learns from down-votes without context.

Comment: I'd also like to ask @José Carlos Santos and others for why they voted to close this question

Comment: Voted to reopen.  The question has enough context for the question to be open and it was not necessary to put it on hold

Comment: @mrjpaxton Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the derivative of $f$ at a point $x = c$ is
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}
$$
One can discuss whether this is defined at the boundary of the domain of the function (it's conventional to say that it isn't, for convenience). However, when the function has a discontinuity the limit definitely isn't defined.

If $c$ is a point of discontinuity, then there are values for $x$ which are arbitrarily close to $c$ where the numerator of the above fraction is nowhere close to $0$. Since the denominator *is* close to $0$ when $x$ is close to $c$, that means that the limit doesn't exist. In this case we can't even say that the limit "is" $\infty$, because there are also values for $x$ close to $c$ for which the numerator *is* close enough to $0$ to give a finite value.

Alternatively, geometrically, the derivative of $f$ at $c$ is the slope of a linear function $g(x) = ax + b$ such that for values of $x$ which are close to $c$ (including being equal to $c$ this time, since there are no denominators in this interpretation), the value of $f(x)$ is close to the value $g(x)$ (for a certain, strictly defined notion of "close"). We can see that for the points of discontinuity you have here, while there is such a line for each side separately, there is no such line that comes close to the graph of $f(x)$ on both sides at the same time. Therefore the function doesn't have a derivative at those points.

Comment: I found that Alex Francisco and Parcly Taxel are the one who vote to close most of the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can define derivative at any point $-5+\epsilon$ and $-1-\epsilon$ $\forall \epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<1$ but at $x=-1$ and $x=-5$ derivative are not defined since the limit of incremental ratio is not defined.